# Angular file not displaying ng-view and not loading jade file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug

Most of the things working fine for me... but in app.js(angluar file) the code doesn't read main.jade file which is written in jade. In my research i got to know that angular doesn't read jade files it only reads html files. So, I took all the code which  is in jade form and converted that to html form and tried to load but empty screen in browser. :( when I opened console in the browser it showed me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquer.js.1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular.js:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular-resource.js:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < angular-route.js:1
>
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.js:1

```
app.js


angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);


angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
    .when('/',     {     templateUrl:'../main.jade',controller:'mainCtrl'});
});

angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.myVar = "Hello Angular";
});


index.jade

extends ../server/includes/layout.jade

  block main-content

    section.content

    div(ng-view)


main.jade

h1 This is a partial

   h2 {{ myVar }}
```

In index.jade div(ng-view) is not working and the whole main.jade files is not working :( :(

Answer (score 2):

Angular expects html, not jade.
Therefore, you have to convert all jade templates to html. For this purpose, you can use different watchers that convert your jade-partials to html on the fly when you change them.